# Selection in mysql with hours available like right outer join

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database. I use MySQL.
Basically, I created an app to manage 'Futsal's Field Order'
So, here we go :

The first table is named **Lapangan** means "Field in Indonesian" :

```
mysql> SELECT id,nama_lapangan FROM lapangan;
+----+---------------+
| id | nama_lapangan |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Lap 01        |
|  2 | Lap 02        |
|  3 | Lap 03        |
+----+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And The Second Table is **Booking :** ,

```
mysql> SELECT id, nomor_booking, date_booking, date_end_booking, lapangan_id FROM `yfutsal`.`booking` LIMIT 1000;
+----+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
| id | nomor_booking | date_booking        | date_end_booking    | lapangan_id |
+----+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
|  1 |             1 | 2017-07-16 10:00:00 | 2017-07-16 12:00:00 |           1 |
|  2 |             2 | 2017-07-16 15:00:00 | 2017-07-16 16:00:00 |           3 |
+----+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

For example, The user start at 08.00 AND end in 23.00.
It means, lap 1 is not available on 10.00 - 12.00.
And same too that lap 3 is not available on 15.00 - 16.00.

The goal is, I want to display the Lapangan (field) that available with hour so, the cashier can choice it.
Something like this :

```
+----+---------------+----------------------+-----------------------+
| id | nama_lapangan |   Available Start    |    Available End      |
+----+---------------+----------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | Lap 01        |  2017-07-16 08:00:00 |   2017-07-16 09:59:00 |
|  1 | Lap 01        |  2017-07-16 12:01:00 |   2017-07-16 23:00:00 |
|  2 | Lap 02        |  2017-07-16 08:00:00 |   2017-07-16 23:00:00 |
|  3 | Lap 03        |  2017-07-16 08:00:00 |   2017-07-16 14:59:00 |
|  3 | Lap 03        |  2017-07-16 16:01:00 |   2017-07-16 23:00:00 |
+----+---------------+----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

try this to set `base_url` in proper way:

```
$root=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

Comment: I change it to  /config/config.php to your code, it not working. It still gives me http. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$root";
```

in `config/config` to

```
$root = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$root";
```

`base_url() function returns` value based on `base_url` constant , you just have to make the constant return `https` instead of `http`